# django-rest-framework: independent GET and PUT in same URL but different generics view

Tags: get, django-rest-framework, put

I'm using django-rest-framework and I need to map in the URL file two generic views with the same url (iḿ already using URLs but not Routes):

I need to allow GET, PUT and DELETE verbs in just one url (like /api/places/222) and allow everyone to get every field with the related Entity Place but just allow to update (PUT) one field using the same url.

Place Entity:

```
- id (not required in PUT)
- name (required always)
- date (not required in PUT but required in POST)
```

URL

```
url(r'^api/places/(?P<pk>\d+)/?$', PlacesDetail.as_view(), name='places-detail'),
```

I tried to use RetrieveDestroyAPIView and UpdateAPIView, but I'm unable to use just one URL.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I suggest you to create a few serializers that satisfy your needs.
Then override the get_serializer method of your view so that the view switches serializers according to an HTTP request method.

This is a quick untested example:

```py
class PlacesDetail(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            serializer_class = FirstSerializer
        elif self.request.method == 'PUT':
            serializer_class = SecondSerializer

        return serializer_class
    ...
```

Look at the base class method's comment:

```py
def get_serializer_class(self):
    """
    Return the class to use for the serializer.
    Defaults to using `self.serializer_class`.

    You may want to override this if you need to provide different
    serializations depending on the incoming request.

    (Eg. admins get full serialization, others get basic serialization)
    """
    ...
```

Comment: Andrey this is a great idea! I didn't know about the get_serializer_class