# Django Rest Framework: Disable field update after object is created

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make my User model RESTful via Django Rest Framework API calls, so that I can create users as well as update their profiles.

However, as I go through a particular verification process with my users, I do not want the users to have the ability to update the username after their account is created. I attempted to use read_only_fields, but that seemed to disable that field in POST operations, so I was unable to specify a username when creating the user object.

How can I go about implementing this? Relevant code for the API as it exists now is below.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'password', 'email')
        write_only_fields = ('password',)

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        user = super(UserSerializer, self).restore_object(attrs, instance)
        user.set_password(attrs['password'])
        return user


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    model = User

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method == 'DELETE':
            return [IsAdminUser()]
        elif self.request.method == 'POST':
            return [AllowAny()]
        else:
            return [IsStaffOrTargetUser()]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I haven't found this question earlier so I asked duplicate. Anyway, one answer that @JPG posted seems better than most of the answers here.  I don't know how to correctly handle this (I'm new to stack overflow), so here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52114443/django-rest-framework-how-to-forbid-users-to-change-their-username

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It seems that you need different serializers for POST and PUT methods. In the serializer for PUT method you are able to just except the username field  (or set the username field as read only).

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    model = User

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        serializer_class = self.serializer_class

        if self.request.method == 'PUT':
            serializer_class = SerializerWithoutUsernameField

        return serializer_class

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method == 'DELETE':
            return [IsAdminUser()]
        elif self.request.method == 'POST':
            return [AllowAny()]
        else:
            return [IsStaffOrTargetUser()]
```

Check this question [django-rest-framework: independent GET and PUT in same URL but different generics view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104487/django-rest-framework-independent-get-and-put-in-same-url-but-different-generic/22107326#22107326)

Comment: That worked like a charm. I just added PATCH to the list of methods that serialize differently. Thanks!

Comment: This quickly becomes unmanageable due to code duplication for large serializers.

Comment: initially started with that one and it works nicely. However, if you want to generate frontend code with swagger-codegen and end up having multiple different front end classes due to different serializer schemas, you'd want to go a different path.

Answer (score 34):

Another option (DRF3 only)

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def get_extra_kwargs(self):
        extra_kwargs = super(MySerializer, self).get_extra_kwargs()
        action = self.context['view'].action

        if action in ['create']:
            kwargs = extra_kwargs.get('ro_oncreate_field', {})
            kwargs['read_only'] = True
            extra_kwargs['ro_oncreate_field'] = kwargs

        elif action in ['update', 'partial_update']:
            kwargs = extra_kwargs.get('ro_onupdate_field', {})
            kwargs['read_only'] = True
            extra_kwargs['ro_onupdate_field'] = kwargs

        return extra_kwargs
```

Comment: Great method.  One minor recommendation, I would use `if self.instance is None:` instead of view.action check.  This allows you to utilize the serializer outside of standard drf views.  I.e. I have a scenario where I utilize the serializer in a celery task while importing data from an external csv file.  The view attribute will be null in this case, but the self.instance check will still work.

Comment: No attribute `action` in ViewSet.

Answer (score 13):

Another method would be to add a validation method, but throw a validation error if the instance already exists and the value has changed:

```
def validate_foo(self, value):                                     
    if self.instance and value != self.instance.foo:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("foo is immutable once set.")
    return value
```

In my case, I wanted a foreign key to never be updated:

```
def validate_foo_id(self, value):                                     
    if self.instance and value.id != self.instance.foo_id:            
        raise serializers.ValidationError("foo_id is immutable once set.")
    return value
```

See also: [Level-field validation in django rest framework 3.1 - access to the old value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089407/level-field-validation-in-django-rest-framework-3-1-access-to-the-old-value)

Comment: I agree that the user should know why the field can not be updated, and this is the only answer that does the job. Unlike Hojat's answer. Here you are still allowed to resend the same serialized object back without the request being refused.

Answer (score 5):

My approach is to modify the `perform_update` method when using generics view classes. I remove the field when update is performed.

```
class UpdateView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    ...
    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        #remove some field
        rem_field = serializer.validated_data.pop('some_field', None)
        serializer.save()
```

Comment: However this doesn't give the API user any clue on why it didn't work. I think you need to raise a proper ValidationError for the field, and that is what happens in the other solutions here that dynamically modify the read_only / write_only attributes on the fields using the extra kwargs method.

Comment: (couldn't edit my comment above): The read_only doesn't actually give a validationerror. But I still think it's good practice in this case to give a validationerror, as it might be illogical for the user to be able to POST a field but not PUT it if it's stripped silently.

Answer (score 2):

I used this approach:

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if getattr(self, 'object', None) is None:
        return super(UserViewSet, self).get_serializer_class()
    else:
        return SerializerWithoutUsernameField
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

Turns out Rest Framework already comes equipped with this functionality. The correct way of having a "create-only" field is by using the `CreateOnlyDefault()` option.

I guess the only thing left to say is Read the Docs!!!
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#createonlydefault

**Old Answer:**

Looks I'm quite late to the party but here are my two cents anyway.

To me it doesn't make sense to have two different serializers just because you want to prevent a field from being updated. I had this exact same issue and the approach I used was to implement my own `validate` method in the Serializer class. In my case, the field I don't want updated is called `owner`. Here is the relevant code:

```
class BusinessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Business
        pass

    def validate(self, data):
        instance = self.instance

        # this means it's an update
        # see also: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#accessing-the-initial-data-and-instance
        if instance is not None: 
            originalOwner = instance.owner

            # if 'dataOwner' is not None it means they're trying to update the owner field
            dataOwner = data.get('owner') 
            if dataOwner is not None and (originalOwner != dataOwner):
                raise ValidationError('Cannot update owner')
        return data
    pass
pass
```

And here is a unit test to validate it:

```
def test_owner_cant_be_updated(self):
    harry = User.objects.get(username='harry')
    jack = User.objects.get(username='jack')

    # create object
    serializer = BusinessSerializer(data={'name': 'My Company', 'owner': harry.id})
    self.assertTrue(serializer.is_valid())
    serializer.save()

    # retrieve object
    business = Business.objects.get(name='My Company')
    self.assertIsNotNone(business)

    # update object
    serializer = BusinessSerializer(business, data={'owner': jack.id}, partial=True)

    # this will be False! owners cannot be updated!
    self.assertFalse(serializer.is_valid())
    pass
```

I raise a `ValidationError` because I don't want to hide the fact that someone tried to perform an invalid operation. If you don't want to do this and you want to allow the operation to be completed without updating the field instead, do the following:

remove the line:

```
raise ValidationError('Cannot update owner')
```

and replace it with:

```
data.update({'owner': originalOwner})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The `CreateOnlyDefault` is not for API submitted data, it's for things that are generated on the server on the initial creation, like the creation date, it's read-only by default for the user.

Answer (score 2):

More **universal way** to "Disable field update after object is created"
- adjust **read_only_fields** per **View.action**

1) add method to Serializer (better to use your own base cls)

```
def get_extra_kwargs(self):
    extra_kwargs = super(BasePerTeamSerializer, self).get_extra_kwargs()
    action = self.context['view'].action
    actions_readonly_fields = getattr(self.Meta, 'actions_readonly_fields', None)
    if actions_readonly_fields:
        for actions, fields in actions_readonly_fields.items():
            if action in actions:
                for field in fields:
                    if extra_kwargs.get(field):
                        extra_kwargs[field]['read_only'] = True
                    else:
                        extra_kwargs[field] = {'read_only': True}
    return extra_kwargs
```

2) Add to Meta of serializer dict named **actions_readonly_fields**

```
class Meta:
    model = YourModel
    fields = '__all__'
    actions_readonly_fields = {
        ('update', 'partial_update'): ('client', )
    }
```

In the example above `client` field will become read-only for actions: 'update', 'partial_update' (ie for PUT, PATCH methods)

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://blog.qax.io/write-once-fields-with-django-rest-framework/) post mentions four different ways to achieve this goal.

This was the cleanest way I think: [collection must not be edited]

```
class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if 'collection' in validated_data:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({
                'collection': 'You must not change this field.',
            })

        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (apart from creating a separate serializer) would be to pop the username from attrs in the restore_object method if the instance is set (which means it's a PATCH / PUT method):

```
def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
    if instance is not None:
        attrs.pop('username', None)
    user = super(UserSerializer, self).restore_object(attrs, instance)
    user.set_password(attrs['password'])
    return user
```

Comment: DRF 3.0 has removed `restore_object`: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create another serializer, you may want to try customizing `get_serializer_class()` inside `MyViewSet`. This has been useful to me for simple projects.

```
# Your clean serializer
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'

# Your hardworking viewset
class MyViewSet(MyParentViewSet):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    model = MyModel

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        serializer_class = self.serializer_class
        if self.request.method in ['PUT', 'PATCH']:
            # setting `exclude` while having `fields` raises an error
            # so set `read_only_fields` if request is PUT/PATCH
            setattr(serializer_class.Meta, 'read_only_fields', ('non_updatable_field',))
            # set serializer_class here instead if you have another serializer for finer control
        return serializer_class
```

> ## [setattr(object, name, value)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr)
>
> This is the counterpart of getattr(). The
>   arguments are an object, a string and an arbitrary value. The string
>   may name an existing attribute or a new attribute. The function
>   assigns the value to the attribute, provided the object allows it. For
>   example, setattr(x, 'foobar', 123) is equivalent to x.foobar = 123.

Comment: But this function is called every time the application is started, how can I make it loaded every time the method 'PATCH' is called? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
class UserUpdateSerializer(UserSerializer):
    class Meta(UserSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ('username', 'email')

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return UserUpdateSerializer if self.action == 'update' else super().get_serializer_class()
```

djangorestframework==3.8.2

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest also looking at [Django pgtrigger](https://pypi.org/project/django-pgtrigger/)

This allows you to install triggers for validation.  I started using it and was very pleased with its simplicity:

Here's one of their examples that prevents a published post from being updated:

```
import pgtrigger
from django.db import models


@pgtrigger.register(
    pgtrigger.Protect(
        operation=pgtrigger.Update,
        condition=pgtrigger.Q(old__status='published')
    )
)
class Post(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(default='unpublished')
    content = models.TextField()
```

The advantage of this approach is it also protects you from `.update()` calls that bypass `.save()`