# Level-field validation in django rest framework 3.1 - access to the old value

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Before updating object the title field is validated. How to access data of serialized object in order to compare `value` with older value of this object?

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = serializers.CharField()

    def validate_title(self, value):
        """
        Check that the blog post is about Django.
        """
        if 'django' not in value.lower():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Blog post is not about Django")
        return value
```

Comment: What sort of comparison do you intend to perform with the old object?

Comment: Also, can you post the code for your views.

Comment: @RahulGupta: Based on the above example, I want to check if the title was changed to the same as was before and raise ValidationError exception if it was. In version 2 of DRF I could use self.object.title inside validate_title method.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to raise exception if `title` value was unchanged?

Comment: @Rahul Gupta this is a little stupid example, so change my mind. I want to raise an exception if someone try to change the title that exists in database (assume the title must be unique).

Comment: Okay.Can you post the code where you are saving and updating the blog in db like `views.py` and `models.py`? That might help.

Comment: @RahulGupta: Sorry, i can't publish this code. Is it possible to do such check in this serializer? The above example comes from DRF documentation. I forgot to say that I use ModelSerializer, not Serializer, and BlogPostSerializer in nested serializer used by another ModelSerializer that is set as serializer_class in my ModelViewSet.

Comment: If its a `ModelSerializer`, then you can use `self.instance` to get access to old object. I have added the ans.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
def validate_title(self, value):
        """
        Check that the title has not changed.
        """
        if self.instance and value != self.instance.title
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Title of a blog post cannot be edited ")
        return value
```

In case of update operations, you will have access to the old object as `self.instance`. Then you can use that to perform your check.

Comment: Probably I made mistake somewhere, but when updating `self.instance` is None. It's a little weird, before upgrading DRF I used self.object in the same way as self.instance and I had access to this object.

Comment: In `update()` , instance is fetched using `get_object()` and then passed to serializer. In the serializer's `__init__`, `self.instance` variable is set. So  you should be able to access the old object. Try putting a debugger like `ipdb` in the `update` method.

Comment: I set `serializer_class=SomeModelSerializer` and in `SomeModelSerializer` I use nested serializer `blogpostserializer = BlogPostSerializer(required=False)` - instance isn't passed here and this is why `self.instance` is None?

Comment: For that, try overriding `get_object()` in your view and see what you are getting.

Comment: Also, the DRF docs say that If you're supporting writable nested representations you'll need to write `.create()` or `.update()` methods that handle saving multiple objects.  http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations

Answer (score 0):

You can get the old value of the field from the serializer context. To do this, use validation class with parameter `requires_context = True`. The `__call__` method will then be called with the `serializer_field` or `serializer` as an additional argument ([manual](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#accessing-the-context)).

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError

class ChangeValidator:
    requires_context = True

    def __call__(self, value, serializer_field):
        instance = getattr(serializer_field.parent, 'instance', None)
        if instance and value == instance.title
            raise ValidationError("Title of a blog must be changed")


class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[ChangeValidator()])
    content = serializers.CharField()
```