# In Django REST framework 3, can one ModelSerializer have different sets of fields for create vs. update?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a DRF 3.3+ API to create/update/retrieve users.  I use the super-convenient [write_only](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#write_only) serializer field argument on my `password` field so that it's used to create/update a user, but is not returned when serializing a user.  However, I want to make `password` required to create a user, but optional to update a user.  Instead of `write_only`, it would be great to have something like `create_only` and `update_only` for finer-grained control.  Since that's not available, I have two serializers that are exactly the same except for the `password` field, which doesn't seem clean.

I'm aware of this answer for DRF 2: [Disable field update after object is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124555), but I was hoping there's a better way to handle this use case in DRF 3.3+.  Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `create_only` or `update_only` like options.

You *could* override `__init__` to see if the `instance` parameter was passed and adjust `fields` accordingly.

I'd have two serialisers, just as you do. So as not to repeat too much, I have one subclass the other, with the subclass adjusting only the `fields` that differed.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't thought of deriving one serializer from another, so until there is a better way, I will go with that approach.  At least this way, there is very little duplicated code (and extra code).

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no inbuilt functionality for that.

But you could do something like this to define the fields depening on the `action`:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # define fields depending on action
    _action_fields = {'update': ['name'], 
                      'create': ['name', 'password'],
                      'default': ['name', 'password']}

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ['name', 'password']  # define max fields you want serialize

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        serializers.ModelSerializer.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        action = kwargs['context']['view'].get('action', 'default')  # I'm not 100% sure if action is defined here. But something similar
        allowed = set(self._action_fields[action])
        existing = set(self.fields.keys())
        for field_name in existing - allowed:
            self.fields.pop(field_name)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the solution above worked better for me and the answer above was first.  I'd happily give you partial credit, but alas SO doesn't allow that :(