# DJango REST Framework Read Only field

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a field `owner` that is a `ForeignKey` to `User` model.

This field is `required` at the time of creation. But it can not be changed later on.

How to make fields `Non-Editable`? Is there any other way than creating multiple serializers?

### Garage Model

```
class GarageDetails(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, )
    name = models.CharField(_('Garage Name'), max_length=254, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(_('Price'), blank=False)
    available_from = models.TimeField(_('Available From'), default=datetime.time(6, 00), blank=False)
    available_till = models.TimeField(_('Available till'), default=datetime.time(18, 00), blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(_('Garage Description'), blank=True, null=True)

    create_date = cmodels.UnixTimestampField(_('Date Added'), auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = cmodels.UnixTimestampField(_('Date Added'), auto_created=True)
    is_available = models.BooleanField(_('Available'), default=True)
```

### Serializer

```
class UserFKSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'email', 'mobile')


class GarageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = UserFKSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = GarageDetails
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'owner', 'create_date', 'update_date')
```

### Views

```
class GarageRegister(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, )
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serialize = GarageSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serialize.is_valid():
            # Create Garage with owner & name

class GarageUpdate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, )
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serialize = GarageSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serialize.is_valid():
            # Update Garage but can't update create_date, id, owner & name
```

Comment: Show us your models, serializers and views files! Then we can help u better..

Comment: @AbijithMg added, please check

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Rest Framework: Disable field update after object is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124555/django-rest-framework-disable-field-update-after-object-is-created)

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo My ask was to do it w/o using multiple serializer.

Answer (score 6):

You could create a different model serializer for each use case (update, create):

specifying that field in [`read_only_fields`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields) in your model serializer:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('a', 'nother', 'field')
        read_only_fields = ('owner',)
```

for django forms instead you set the [`disabled` field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#disabled):

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       form.fields['owner'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
```

Comment: If `owner` is a read only field in serializer, how would the OP create the model? It is specified in the question that the field is required only at the time of creation and not updation.

Comment: @AKS you have two model serializers for each use case

Comment: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/1604 There is a discussion going on the same..

Comment: @DRC You should include this information in your answer if you think that using two model serializers is the way to go.

Comment: I think you would also need to specify that how to select one of these serializers for create/update cases in views.

Comment: @AKS no worries. I can do that!

Comment: @DRC thanks! I know one of the option is to create multiple serializer. But is that the best one?

Comment: @iamhssingh personally I like to create different serializers for different use cases, maybe rely on inheritance to not repeat common things. Another option would be to parametrize the constructor to set something on the field, for example `MyModelForm(update=True) ` in __init__ `update = kwargs.pop('update'); super()... ; form.fields['owner'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = update`

Comment: @DRC please check code. I am not using DJango Forms. I just added code for some clarity. Apologies for not doing so earlier!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by overriding the "update" method as follows:

```
  def update(self, instance, validated_data):                                                     
      if 'owner' in validated_data:                                                              
          del validated_data['owner']                                                            
      return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

This will silently ignore the owner field on updates. If you want to you may instead "raise ValidationError('owner may not be set on updates')" but if you do so you may want to read the model instance and only raise the error if it's actually a change to avoid false positives.

Also, if you're using the python2, the "super" call needs to be "super(GarageSerializer, self)" or some such.