# Django Rest Framework how to forbid users to change their username?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm creating `UserSerializer` and want to allow users to create new accounts but forbid them to change their usernames. There is a `read_only` attribute that I can apply but then users won't be able to set a username when creating a new one. But without that It allows me to change it. There is also a `required` attribute which unfortunately cannot be used with read_only. There is no other relevant attribute.
One solution is to create 2 different Serializers one for creating User and another from changing him, but that seems the ugly and wrong thing to do. Do you have any suggestions on how to accomplish that without writing 2 serializers?

Thanks for any advice.

PS: I'm using python3.6 and django2.1

EDIT: I'm using `generics.{ListCreateAPIView|RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView}` classes for views. Like this:

```
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class UserDetails(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    # this magic means (read only request OR accessing user is the same user being edited OR user is admin)
    permission_classes = (perm_or(ReadOnly, perm_or(IsUserOwner, IsAdmin)),)

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

EDIT2: There is a duplicate question (probably mine is duplicate) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124555/django-rest-framework-disable-field-update-after-object-is-created/22133032)

Comment: Are you using a ModelViewset class ?

Comment: The best approach would be to implement the logic in the model. When you save an instance check if it has set pk. If yes it is updating, if no it is creating. If it is updating, disallow changing the value of username.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Rest Framework: Disable field update after object is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124555/django-rest-framework-disable-field-update-after-object-is-created)

Comment: Yup, haven't found it before, but still JPG's answer is I believe better than all answers in the other question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using a **`viewset`** class for your view, then you could override the **`init`** method of serializer as,

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'view' in self.context and self.context['view'].action in ['update', 'partial_update']:
            self.fields.pop('username', None)

    class Meta:
        ....
```

If you are trying to update the username field while update (`HTTP PUT`) or partial update (`HTTP PATCH`), the serializer will remove the **`username`** field from the list of fields and hence it wont affect the data/model

**UPDATE**
Why the above answer not woking with ***documentaion API***?
From the [doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/)

> Note: By default `include_docs_urls` configures the underlying SchemaView to generate public schemas. ***This means that views will not be instantiated with a request instance. i.e. Inside the view self.request will be `None`.***

In the answer, the fields are ***pops out*** **dynamically** with the help of a *request* object.
So, If you wish to handle API documentaion also, define ***multiple*** serializer and use **`get_serializer_class()`** method efficently. That's the DRF way.

Comment: Hey sorry I haven't mentioned it  I use `generics.RetriveUpdateDestroyAPIView`

Comment: @Kaifer If so, this answer definitely work as expected

Comment: Hey, it works but the generated documentation doesn't reflect this change.

Comment: Generated documentation ? I dont get that :(

Comment: Rest Framework will generate a schema for CoreAPI and also HTML documentation for all endpoints see DRF documentation here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/

Comment: @JanKaifer Updated the answer

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps, one of the possible approaches would be to create a `RegistrationSerializer` which you use only in registration process/endpoint.

And then, you create another serializer `UserSerializer` where you make username read_only field and you use this serializer everywhere else ( eg. when updating user).

Answer (score 2):

Anwser from @JPG is pretty accurate, but it has one limitation. You can use the serializer only in DRF views, because in other views or anywhere else the context will not have view.actions. To fix it `self.instance` can be used. It will make the code shorter and more versatile. Also instead of popping the field its better to make it read only, so that it can still be viewed but cannot be changed.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance is not None:  # if object is being created the instance doesn't exist yet, otherwise it exists.
            # self.fields.pop('username', None)
            self.fields.get('username').read_only = True  # An even better solution is to make the field read only instead of popping it.

    class Meta:
        ....
```

Another possible solution is to use CreateOnlyDefault() which is a builtin feature in DRF now. You can read more about it [here in the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#createonlydefault)