# How to make a field editable=False in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've a serializer. I want to restrict updating a field. How would I do that?

```
class ABCSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        """Meta."""

        model = ModelA
        fields = ('colA', 'colB', 'colC',)
```

`colA` is a required field while creating the object. However, it should not be allowed to update. How can I do that??

Comment: No, it;s not. What is this? I want `colA` is a required field while creating the object. However, it should not be allowed to update (PUT). Adding `colA` to `write-only` will allow the field to be editable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Rest Framework: Disable field update after object is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124555/django-rest-framework-disable-field-update-after-object-is-created)

Answer (score 8):

You can use Django REST Frameworks [field-level validation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation) by validating that field has not changed on update like so:

```py
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError

class ABCSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    colA = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)

    def validate_colA(self, value):
        if self.instance and self.instance.colA != value:
            raise ValidationError("You may not edit colA")
        return value

    class Meta:
        """Meta."""

        model = ModelA
        fields = ('colA', 'colB', 'colC',)
```

This will check whether or not this is an update (via checking if an instance is populated on the serializer) and if so it will then check to see if you have made a change to the field and if you have it will throw a `ValidationError`. The benefit of this approach is that you can keep your view code the same as before and continue to keep your validation behaviour in your serializer.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need different serializers for `PUT` and `POST` methods. In the serializer for the `PUT` method you can set the `colA` field to `readonly`

```
class ABCViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ABCSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        serializer_class = self.serializer_class
        if self.request.method == 'PUT':
            serializer_class = SerializerWithReadOnlyColA
        return serializer_class
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's too late to answer but this may be useful for others:)

you can solve your problem this way:

```
    class ABCSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = ModelA
            fields = ('colA', 'colB', 'colC',)
        
        def get_fields(self):
            fields = super().get_fields()
            if self.instance:
                fields["colA"].read_only = True
            return fields
```

When you want to create, the `self.instance` is None, it will pass the if clause, and in case of updating the if clause will make the field read only and non-editable.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the serializer's `update` method to only update fields that you want.

```
class ABCSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.colB = validated_data.get('colB', instance.colB)
        instance.colC = validated_data.get('colC', instance.colC)
        # do nothing to instance.colA
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ('colA', 'colB', 'colC',)
```

Or if you have many fields, and just want to omit updating `colA`, you could write your `update` method like this:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    validated_data.pop('colA') # validated_data no longer has colA
    return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

You can read more about overriding `update` here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances

Answer (score -2):

You can do this with the `read_only_fields`option

```
class ABCSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        """Meta."""

        model = ModelA
        fields = ('colB', 'colC',)
        read_only_fields = ('colA',)
```

Comment: I want `colA` is a required field while creating the object. However, your solution will not provide me to `write` it.