# Django Rest Framework set a field read_only after record is created

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using `Django 2.x` and `Django REST Framework`.

I have a model with `contact` as a foreign key

```
class AmountGiven(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    amount = models.FloatField(help_text='Amount given to the contact')
    given_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

and serializer like

```
class AmountGivenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    mode_of_payment = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=ModeOfPayment.objects.all())
    contact_detail = ContactSerializer(source='contact', read_only=True)
    contact = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Contact.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = AmountGiven
        depth = 1
        fields = (
            'id', 'contact', 'contact_detail', 'amount', 'given_date', 'created'
        )
```

`contact` field is required while creating a new record. But I do not want `contact` to be modified once it is created.

But when I send only `amount` with `PUT` method it says

```
{
    "contact": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

And when I use `PATCH` method, it works fine but if passing some other value for `contact`, it is updating `contact` as well.

**I want to make `contact` field `not-required` while updating existing record. And even if it is passed, use the earlier one instead of setting the new data.**

> Trial 2

I tried overriding the `contact` field in the request to the previously stored value so that in case if changed `contact` is passed or no `contact` is passed, it will save earlier one.

So, in the viewset add the function

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = self.get_object()
    request.data['contact'] = obj.contact_id
    return super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

But this is giving error as

```
This QueryDict instance is immutable
```

Comment: you need to make it read only when updating.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Rest Framework: Disable field update after object is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124555/django-rest-framework-disable-field-update-after-object-is-created)

Answer (score 2):

Use `__init__` method of serializer to make it read when object is being updated:

```
class AmountGivenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """If object is being updated don't allow contact to be changed."""
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance is not None:
            self.fields.get('parent').read_only = True
            # self.fields.pop('parent') # or remove the field


    mode_of_payment = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=ModeOfPayment.objects.all())
    contact_detail = ContactSerializer(source='contact', read_only=True)
    contact = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Contact.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = AmountGiven
        depth = 1
        fields = (
            'id', 'contact', 'contact_detail', 'amount', 'given_date', 'created'
        )
```

Using `self.context['view'].action` is not recommended as it will not work when using the serializer out of DRF, eg. in normal Django views. It's best to use `self.instance` as it will work in every situation.

Answer (score 2):

If your viewset is a `ModelViewSet`, you can overwrite the `perform_update` hook (because `ModelViewSet` inherits from [`GenericAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods) (take a look at "Save and deletion hooks"). You can access the old contact using the serializer's [`instance`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#accessing-the-initial-data-and-instance) field:

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # ... other stuff

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(contact=serializer.instance.contact)
```

So you will have to provide a contact, but no matter which contact you provide, it will always use the old saved contact when updating.