# Django REST serializer required field

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a simple serializer with one required field:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('field1', 'field2')
```

In my model there is an 'url' field which is required to create new object (method: POST). I would like to set `required: False` for PUT method. How can I achieve that? Thanks for any clues...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to change/set one or multiple fields of an existing MyModel instance.

In such case, you need to pass a `partial=True` keyword argument to serializer. Then even if you PUT or PATCH without `url` field in data, your serializer.is_valid() would evaluate to True.

https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2019/04/drf-polls/#edit-a-poll-question should help if my assumption about your question is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer helpful: [Django Rest Framework set a field read_only after record is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52904147/django-rest-framework-set-a-field-read-only-after-record-is-created) .

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance is not None:
            self.fields.get('url').read_only = True
```

This code works fine.